# Terraform - aws_config_config_rule - setting event_source to specific ResourceType

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

I am using Terraform to configure AWS Config Custom rules. In the custom rule config I want to limit the event 'Resource' to 'CloudTrail:Trail' but the only valid value I can find is the default value of 'aws.config'.

Is this the only valid 'Resource' you can specify in a Terraform built AWS Custom Config Rule?

```
resource "aws_config_config_rule" "custom_rule_01" {
  name        = "CUSTOM_CloudTrail_EnableLogFileValidation"
  description = "Some Description"

  source {
    owner             = "CUSTOM_LAMBDA"
    source_identifier = "${aws_lambda_function.lambda_01.arn}"

    source_detail {
      event_source = "**aws.config**"
      message_type = "ConfigurationItemChangeNotification"
    }
  }
}
```

Appreciate any guidance.

Answer (score 3):

https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/config_config_rule.html#source-1

> event_source - (Optional) The source of the event, such as an AWS service, that triggers AWS Config to evaluate your AWS resources. **This defaults to aws.config and is the only valid value.**

What you are looking for is `resourceType`

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/config/latest/APIReference/API_ResourceIdentifier.html#config-Type-ResourceIdentifier-resourceType

Which have the type of `AWS::CloudTrail::Trail`

Comment: Added 'compliance_resource_types = ["AWS::CloudTrail::Trail"]' as a list under "scope {}".

Worked great.